# Jenkins Pipeline JUnit plugin

Tags: jenkins, junit, jenkins-pipeline

I am developing a build process (pipeline) in which I have two phases which run different JUnits. I want to display both results in the Jenkins job overview (above pipeline steps) with a usage of JUnit plugin. However, I see only one chart with confusing data. For first JUnit phase, I have about 700 tests, for the second about 100 so in the chart, I see a pick (because the chart is updated twice during one build).
Is it possible to have two charts - one for each build phase so reports are independent?

To get JUnit report I am using:

```
junit 'build/reports/**/*.xml'
```

I am calling the above command twice (with different xml). However, it updates the same chart.

Comment: Convert your xml outputs to html and use https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/HTML+Publisher+Plugin to publish them

Comment: I read the documentation for this plugin and it seems it will create two reports but only one Test Result Trend chart. Unfortunately, I need two.

Comment: Afaik a Jenkins job can always only have one of a type of trend chart (i.e. one findbugs trend, one testcoverage graph, one test result trend, ...). You cannot have multiple charts of one type. Perhaps you should have two jobs instead?

Comment: I have just found https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Multi+Module+Tests+Publisher. I think it can help me with a problem. I will let you know

Comment: Didn't know about that - good find and thanks for sharing.